# Change position of navbar-brand

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I' d like to move my `navbar-brand`, just a bit to the right. The default position overlaps, a little, with another button. How can I do it?
Here is a bit of my html code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="navbar-btn">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></sp<an>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" >Agora</a>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <form class="form-inline mx-auto my-2">
                            <input class="form-control mr-sm-1" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
```

Do i have to use CSS?
Code is well accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i understood that you want to get the button a little bet right from his current position

you can see this example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dLyVwX)

so you can use bootstrap positioning classes with the `navbar-brand` as usual like

`ml-*, mr-*`

Answer (score 0):

Add this in you CSS file.

```
.navbar-brand
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin: auto;
}
```

You can check the running demo [here](https://codepen.io/AbdiHaikal/pen/eEolt). Position is `center` in demo, adjust the position to `right` or whatever you like.

Comment: thanks for the answer, however the answer of @Salem Code fits better with what I asked :)